# How does a request reaches Resource class in Jersey RESTful API?

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey, dropwizard

I have been using Jersey, Tomcat, and Dropwizard for quite some time. But I am still not able to get what all actions happen from the point a request reaches port 8080 of a server to the point when it hits one of the methods annotated with `@Path`.

It will be really helpful if someone can help me with all(or a few important) layers in the whole architecture of restful API. For simplicity assume I have an application built with glassfish-jersey and deployed as the fat war using Tomcat.

Answer (score 2):

When Jersey starts up, it will introspect registered resource classes and build a model of all the resources. This model includes the resource classes, the resources methods, and the paths and content-types that map to those resources/resource methods.

Jersey itself runs as a [Servlet](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/jakarta-servlet-spec-5.0.html#what-is-a-servlet) inside a Servlet container (e.g. Tomcat, Grizzly). The entry point Servlet is the Jersey [`ServletContainer`](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/master/containers/jersey-servlet-core/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletContainer.java). So when a request comes in, if the requested URI matches the configured servlet-mapping, the Servlet container will forward the request to the Jersey Servlet. Based on the requested URI and [content negotiation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation), Jersey will go into the model mapping and determine which resource class and method should be called, and then call that method.

Comment: thank you. What is the entry point in Grizzly source code?

Comment: Is there a good document that can help me understand Servelet Container architecture?

Comment: That's beyond my scope of my knowledge. I don't know much about the internals of the different servers.

Comment: Here is a document for the architecture of Tomcat 5. I couldn't find a newer one https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/architecture/overview.html